# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects - saving model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pickle

I have model with custom layer. Custom layers is as below

```
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, loaded_model):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__()
        self.loaded_model = loaded_model

    def build(self, input_shape):
        pass

    def get_config(self):

        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'loaded_model': self.loaded_model
        })
        return config

    def call(self, x):
        stacked_output = []
        for t in tf.unstack(x, axis=-1):
            single_image = tf.expand_dims(t, axis=-1)
            for i in range(10):
                single_image = self.loaded_model.get_layer(index=i)(single_image)
            stacked_output.append(single_image)
            output = tf.stack(stacked_output, axis=-1)
            # print(output.shape)
        return output
```

Main model with custom layer:

```
def create_model():
    trajectory_input = Input(shape=(n_steps, feature_count), name='trajectory_input')
    image_input = Input(shape=(128, 128, n_steps), name='image_input')

    x_aware = CustomLayer(loaded_model)(image_input)
    x_aware = Reshape((1, 501760))(x_aware)

    x = (Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))(trajectory_input)
    x = Reshape((1, 32 * n_steps))(x)

    x = concatenate([x, x_aware])

    output_regression = (Dense(2, name='main_output'))(x_reg)

    adam = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    model = Model(inputs=[trajectory_input, image_input], outputs=output_regression)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse', metrics=[euc_dist_1, euc_dist_2])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

when I try to save model using `model.save("model.h5")` initially I ended up with

```
NotImplementedError: Layers with arguments in __init__ must override `get_config`
```

but once I include `get_config` in CustomLayer solved the error.

But now I get

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I am using pretrained model as a custom layer.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: I had this issue because the environments used for training and loading the model were different, when I loaded the model the in same environment, the error disappears.